# What is the word for pretending to write in a language

Tags: single-word-requests

For example the fake Swedish in the introduction of Monty Python and the Holy Grail, "Mynd you, møøse bites Kan be pretti nasti".

What is the word for a word or sentence written in that way?

Answer (score 1):

Macaronic language. Also, humorous fake Latin is often called cod, dog, or mock Latin, and the use of these prefixes before 'Swedish' would be understandable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Latin

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Macaronic_language